# RDL/RDLC Matrix Report Column Header Formatting

Tags: matrix, rdlc, rdl, ssrs-tablix

I am trying to format column headers in my Matrix report on an RDLC report.  I have the columns specified as DateTime in my dataset and if I leave the column alone Ex:

```
=Fields!FinancialsTableMonthYear.Value
```

It displays fine Ex: 1/1/2009 | 2/1/2009 | 3/1/2009 Etc...

But if I try and put any formatting on the column header Ex:

```
=MonthName(Fields!FinancialsTableMonthYear.Value, true)
```

It will display Ex: #Error | #Error | #Error Etc...

I have also tried Ex:

```
=Year(Fields!FinancialsTableMonthYear.Value)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `=MonthName(Month(Fields!FinancialsTableMonthYear.Value))`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the name of the month, you can use this format:

```
Format(Fields!FinancialsTableMonthYear.Value, "MMM")
```

Change the "MMM" to any format you want.